# ошибка с vector push_back

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть 2 класса А и В  нужно создать контейнер отдельно  для каждого класса через метод create который template  котрый заполняет контейнер типом в зависимости от параметера которого передали

```
    template <typename T>
vector<T> create(tring tipe)
{
  vector<T>test;
  if (tipe == "a")
  {
    test.push_back(A());
  }
  if (tipe == "b")
  {
    test.push_back(B());
  }
   return test;
}
void d()
{   
  vector<A>a;   
  vector<B>b;    
  a = create<A>("a");
  b = create<B>("b");
}
```

при билде такая ошибка 'void std::vector<А,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(_Ty &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'А' to 'const В &'

как это решить?

Comment: a = create<A>("a") ?

Comment: да, я забыл напистаь тут

Comment: "...котрый заполняет контейнер типом в зависимости от параметера которого передали" - это невозможно реализовать. Параметер функции - значение времени выполнения. Тип элемента контейнера - жестко определяется на стадии компиляции. Невозможно напрямую поместить в контейнер то, чей тип не зафиксирован на стадии компиляции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут проблема в том, что тип элемента, который можно положить в вектор, задается параметром шаблона `T` на этапе компиляции, а не строкой на этапе выполнения. Соответственно создать вектор с одним элементом куда проще:

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> create(void)
{
   vector<T> test{};
   test.push_back(T{});  
   return test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Может так?

```
#include <vector>

struct A {};
struct B {};

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> Create(const T& o)
{
    std::vector<T> ret{o};
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> vA = Create(A{} );
    std::vector<B> vB = Create(B{} );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А зачем dummy argument?

Comment: для инстанцирование шаблона

Comment: ну а если А и В приниамют  разное количество параметров, скажем А(5); В("test",0);

Comment: Почему тогда просто не написать `Create<A>()`? То же количество символов в местах вызова, но при этом большее в заголовке функции --- не говоря о том, что компилятор теперь формально обязан каждый раз создавать объект.